# joing two tables with count values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables:

```
items:
id    pr1  pr2
--------------
1     11   22
...
```

and a table of comments associated with the items:

```
comments:
item_id text
------------
1 "cool"
1 "very good"
...
```

Now I want to get a table with columns `item_id pr1 pr2 count(comments)`. What is the best way to get it? Thanks!

Comment: First I can create a table from comments just having item_id, count(comments) using group by. Then I can join that table with items table. But I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Don't create a table, just join both tables and group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it in one single query:

```
SELECT items.id, 
       items.pr1, 
       items.pr2, 
       COUNT(*) AS comment_count
FROM   items 
       INNER JOIN comments 
               ON items.id = comments.item_id 
GROUP  BY items.id, 
          items.pr1, 
          items.pr2
```

- See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e548c/2).

**EDIT**:

If all the ungrouped columns are functionnally dependent of the grouped one, it appears that you can group by only this column (as Yash did):

```
SELECT items.id, 
       items.pr1, 
       items.pr2, 
       COUNT(*) AS comment_count
FROM   items 
       INNER JOIN comments 
               ON items.id = comments.item_id 
GROUP  BY items.id
```

See:

- [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8cf1b/2)
- [PostGres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

**EDIT 2**:

About adding a second table (let's take `tags`):

You can't just go on `COUNT`ing on `*`. Try that:

```
SELECT items.id, 
       items.pr1, 
       items.pr2, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT comments.*) AS comment_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT tags.*) AS tags_count
FROM   items 
       INNER JOIN comments 
               ON items.id = comments.item_id 
       INNER JOIN tags 
               ON items.id = tags.item_id 
GROUP  BY items.id, 
       items.pr1, 
       items.pr2
```

By using `DISTINCT`, you'll `COUNT` each row in `comments` only once, and the same with `tags`.

- One more [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b16b2/3).

Comment: What is if there is another table like comments, say tags, and in the final result I want to show both comments count and tags count?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select items.id, items.pr1, items.pr2, count(*) as comment from items,comments where items.id = comments.item_id group by items.id
```

Comment: Won't work if you only group by items.id. Also, the implicit join notation is deprecated (since 92).

Comment: @X.L.Ant Try it on your system. it will give output. I did run successfully.

Comment: I did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e548c/1 Doesn't work. Don't try it on MySQL, which has a specific way of grouping. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Actually @Yash's code worked for me on PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: I believe you, maybe there are some variations in PostGreSQL that I don't know of that allow this kind of grouping (the mysql way). That said, this is not standard SQL, meaning that this won't work on other RDBMS (or some other flavours/config of Postgres obviously).

Comment: I found what happens, and why it didn't work on my first fiddle. See my edited answer. @Yash, +1 for making me discover this :)